# How to handle the Optimistic concurrency violation in the SQL DB?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm working on a real estate windows forms application on **C#** and **SQL Server**, which is also a multi-user app. I'm **not** using Entity Framework or LINQ in it!

I'm struggling on how to properly handle the **optmistic concurrency violation**. Assume there are two tables in DB, `Properties` and `Addresses`.

- *Properties* contain general property details such as `type of
  property`, `no of rooms`, `price` etc.
- *Addresses* has the property addresses.

When my form loads, it loads all the information of properties to a `datagridview`. In this case it load all information in `Properties` and `Addresses` table to a `datagridview`.

When the user clicks a row on `datagridview` it loads the data on that row to an editing form. Then user updates and updates the db. In this situation an **optimistic concurrency violation** (OCV) can occur.

But How do I store the `rowversion` value of data that was fetched from Properties and Addresses in such a way that will help to handle this OCV violation?

Initially I was thinking about when the user double clicks on the row, the `rowversions` for that record in the **Properties** and **Addresses** tables can be stored in a **transaction table**. But after the records been loaded their `rowversion` values can be changed by another user thus whats displayed on the `datagridview` might be out dated. So when the user clicks a row, i need to send the exact data on the "grid" (not in DB) to the editing form along with their original `rowversion` values. Whats the proper way to do this?

**P.S.** I was told the proper way to handle OCV is to handle it in the SQL server and not in the ADO .NET since OCV is a database operation. So i would prefer guidance to handle it in the database!

thanks

Comment: In the future, please don't use **unnecessary** or `incorrect` emphasis, as it makes the question harder to read.

Comment: sorry about that, i was trying to make it more understandable : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optimistic concurrency should be handle by database. For instance

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  Id int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  FirstName nvarchar (256) NULL,
  LastName nvarchar (256) NULL,
  _rowVersion rowversion NOT NULL -- Value generated by SQL Server each time the row is updated
)
```

When loading rows you need to get the row version generated by SQL Server

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, _rowVersion 
FROM Customer
```

When saving the row, you have to add a test to ensure the RowVersion has not changed between the time you load the row and now

```
UPDATE Customer SET
  FirstName = @FirstName,
  LastName] = @LastName,
WHERE Id = @Id AND _rowVersion] = @_rowVersion -- Update using the row version

-- This part can be done in the .NET application if you prefer
SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
IF(@rowcount = 0) -- No row updated => Concurrency Error
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Concurrency error in procedure %s', 16, 1, 'Customer_Save')
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: in my case the app loads the datagrid fetched from two tables properties and Addresses.
1. in this case i need to return two Rowversion values one in teh Properties and one in the Addresses? 
2. I need to add a property in the business logical layer class "Property" to hold these rowversions?

Comment: One RowVersion column by table. You have to store the RowVersion in your application, so yes you need to add a property to store this value.